# Missing Code Signing Entitlements - No entitlements found in bundle for executable

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing

I'm getting letters from iTunes connect with the following error:
Missing Code Signing Entitlements - No entitlements found in bundle for executable 
However, there were some successful trials, when the app was submitted and set to inactive status without any errors . But when I tried to submit it again with **the same code signing settings** I got this error. Has anyone got the same problem and is there any way out of it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try to edit your provisioning profile and rebuild project with it.

Comment: what should be changed in provisioning profile?

Comment: just edit it. Apple changed smth in profile generation process on their side. For me after that operation all warnings went away.

Comment: I mean, there's nothing to change in provisioning profile on developr.apple.com : only profile name and app id can be changed, e.g. changing the name didn't help (after changing I downloaded new profile used it instead of old one)

Answer (score 0):

Go to projects Target then Build Setting ,serach for code signing set Provisioning profile & code signing identity & run the app.
refer this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html

Comment: Yes, I've done that : Provisioning profile was set to the one, I had created and downloaded before (for distribution), for "release" and "andy iOS sdk" iPhone distribution option was chosen. 
Bty, that doesn't explain, why there are some rare trials which pass successfully with inactive status