# Missing Code Signing Entitlements - No entitlements found in bundle 'com.google.Googleplus'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

i am submitting the application on app store.
[image: validate the app]
[image: validation fail error]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712650/missing-code-signing-entitlements-no-entitlements-found-in-bundle-for-executab Also check your bundle identifire

Comment: its not working for me.

Comment: Is ur production certificate is ok. Have u checked?

Comment: yes .its valid i check it

Comment: which profiles u selected? can u paste pic of code signing here? e.g same like i posted in my answer

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/reddue1rk26se3b/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-09%20at%205.47.10%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: sorry.now i post link dropbox

Comment: In your provisioning profile select godintrest certi instead of Automatic. Problem is nothing but try to set proper certificate u created for production.

Comment: your problem solved or not?

Comment: not still.but try to fix it

Comment: did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

Add into your Podfile:

pod 'googleplus-ios-sdk', '~> 1.7.1'

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Before you **Product > Archive** check that you are using an AppStore Distribution Provisioning Profile. Go to **Build Settings > Code Signing** and change Distribution Identity for Release and Provisioning Profile for Release.

[image: Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile for Release]

ref : [ERROR ITMS-9000: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle" - How to change app ID name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347770/error-itms-9000-missing-code-signing-entitlements-no-entitlements-found-in-bu)

Comment: make sure to use bundle identifier with same App id. Recheck it